# FactoryBoy related factory objects not available in post_generation

Tags: django, factory-boy

I have a factory for a Django model (Questionnaire) where I create a set of related items in a trait (Questions that have a foreign key pointing to the Questionnaire). The Questionnaire also has a many-to-many field pointing to a Dimension model. The factory, optionally, adds a set of Dimension objects to the Questionnaire in a post_generation method. Now, if questions have been added, I want to set the dimension field on each of them to a random choice from these dimensions. This is what I have:

```py
class QuestionnaireFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Questionnaire

    class Params:
        with_questions = Trait(
            questions=RelatedFactoryList(
                QuestionFactory,
                "questionnaire",
                size=3,
                with_choices=True,
            )
        )

    # Add dimensions to the questionnaire.
    @factory.post_generation
    def dimensions(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        # First add the dimensions to the questionnaire.
        if create and extracted:
            self.dimensions.add(*extracted)
            # What I want to do: Add random dimension to each question (doesn't work)
            for question in self.question_set.all():
                question.dimension = Faker("random_element", elements=extracted)
                question.save()
```

Which I would call with:

```py
dimensions = factories.DimensionFactory.create_batch(3)
questionnaire = factories.QuestionnaireFactory.create(with_questions=True, dimensions=dimensions)
```

However, self.question_set.all() is empty in the post_generation hook. So, with the code as above, the dimension field is not being set on any question. It appears that the creation of the questions is happening after the post_generation hook.

I also tried setting the dimension on the questions in the trait:

```py
# ...
size=3,
dimension=Maybe("dimensions", yes_declaration=Faker("random_element", elements=factory.SelfAttribute("dimensions")), no_declaration=None),
with_choices=True,
# ...
```

but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the django orm will call `bulk_create` rather than `save` on the model when you call by dereferencing a list into the `add` function . . .try

```
@factory.post_generation
def dimensions(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    . . . 
    if create and extracted:
        for dimension in extracted:
            self.dimensions.add(dimension)
        . . .
```

instead

Comment: The problem is that the questions are not yet set when the ```dimensions``` function is called. The dimensions are being set correctly on the model, but it never enters the loop where question.dimension is set. However, after I call e.g.```QuestionnaireFactory.create(with_questions=True, dimensions=[DimensionFactory(), DimensionFactory()])``` then the questions are set, so they are being set after the @factroy.post_generation hooks are called.